# How to access form data from a setter without using object literal values?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I need to add setter to the below JavaScript Module:

In the below code I am simply returning the form data to the module object.
I need to add setter functionality so that I can do minimal check on the user input.

```
var Mod = (function(){

    var module = {};
    var element = document.forms.[0];

    Object.defineProperty(module, 'Country', {

        get: function () {

            return element.txtCountry.value;            
        }

    });

        Object.defineProperty(module, 'City', {

        get: function () {

            return element.txtCity.value;           
        }

    });

    return module;

})();
```

However, all of the examples I have come across, including those on MDN shows an object with literal values:

Like this one:

```
var module = {

  Country: "United States",

  get function() { 

    return this.Country;

  },

  set function(x) {

    this.Country = x + ' ' + somethingElse;
  }

};
```

How do I add the setter to return data to the object without literal object members?

Finally I am calling the module like this:

```
var btn = document.getElementById( 'btnDataEntry' );
var result = document.getElementById('result');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    var t = document.createTextNode(Mod.Country + ',' + Mod.City);  

    result.appendChild(t);

    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

*Update (Additional Info):*
*In the most simplest form I want to perform checks in the `setter`, something like this:*

```
var Mod = (function(){

    var module = {};
    var element = document.forms.dataEntry;

    Object.defineProperty(module, 'Country', {

        get: function () {

            return Country;

        },

        set: function(val) {

            if( val == 'A') {

              val = element.txtCountry.value;

            }
        }
    });

    return module;

})();
```

***Update: (Solution).***

So as simple as this may seem, it can become confusing because *JavaScript* is more abstract when it comes to how one can accomplish certain task.

The problem is, when using setter in an `Object.defineProperty()` method, you have to pass the value using a dot notation to the object, and by also using a variable within the scope of the function to emulate a private member.

If you look at my ***previous*** code, you will see that I was passing the form data directly within the `getter`, this defeats the entire purpose of having a `getter/setter`.

Here is a complete working code: Based on readings and example from the following book: *The Principles of Object-Oriented JavaScript: By Nicholas C. Zakas.*

*Code:*

```
var LocationData = (function(){

    var location = {};

    //Private member to eliminate global scope
    var _country;

    Object.defineProperty(location, "Country", {

        get: function() {

            return this._country;

            },

            set: function(value) {

            if(value === 'A') {

                this._country = value;

            } else {

                this._country = 'X';
            }

        }

    });

    return location;

})();


var btn = document.getElementById( 'btnDataEntry' );
var result = document.getElementById('result');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    var element = document.forms[0];

    //Pass the value to the method
    LocationData.Country = element.txtCountry.value;

    var t = document.createTextNode(LocationData.Country);  

    result.appendChild(t);

    e.preventDefault();

}, false);
```

Comment: Why exactly can't you use the same method in `defineProperty`??

Comment: I have tried playing around with the code and referring to MDN but as I indicated, all the examples I read simply showed literal values, no connection to form data.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying (and failing) to do. Can you show what you'd like to have? what usage you're trying to get?

Comment: Please see update: Thanks.

Comment: Other then some confusion in your required code (`return Country` makes no sense, `val = element...` should probably be the other way around), I still don't see what the problem is.

Comment: Feel free to post your solution as an Answer to your own Question. This is generally better than posting in the Question.

Answer (score 0):

Define the setter in the same `defineProperty` call where you define the getter:

```
Object.defineProperty(module, 'City', {

        get: function () {

            return element.txtCity.value;           
        },
        set: function (value) {
            // do minimal check
            element.txtCity.value = value;           
        }

    });
```

Comment: What am I performing the validation on?
I am still getting the same data returned regardless of where I am checking, using an `if statement.`